# Reading Json file is slow when uploading to IIS

Tags: json, .net, angular, asp.net-core, iis

I uploaded .Net core/ Angular project into IIS. I have a code to write into json file and read from json file.

In the localhost, It is not taking a second to write/read Json file, but after upload and hosted in IIS, it is taking 10 seconds to write/read json file.

This is the code to write for Json file

```
string result ={This contains JSON response};
string lstrfilename = "D:\\LOG\\avail.json";
 File.WriteAllText(lstrpath, result);
```

This is the code to read Json file

```
 string lstrpath = "D:\\LOG\\avail.json";
string lstrData =File.ReadAllText(lstrpath);
```

Is there anything I need to consider when upload and host to IIS?. How can I get rid of slowness when reading JSON file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did u test? Maybe u send a big JSON to an API endpoint and the network in fact is slow and not the read/write.

Comment: Same Json file sent in localhost and IIS

Comment: Localhost is not relevant and the file u upload there in this context. Use  System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew() and write it to a log or so to understand if this is the problem (but I doubt).

Comment: are you running any antivirus software? try enabling caching . set logging to see which operation is taking time